# Derivative of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In a differential equation

$y' = x^2 - y^2$

then why does

$y'' = 2x - 2yy'$

shouldn't

$y'' = \frac{d}{dx}y' = 2x - 2y$

I am trying to understand ODE's, so maybe a simple question requiring a simple response. Where is the extra y' coming from on $2yy'$

Comment: $$y = y(x) \implies (y^{2})' = (y \cdot y)' = y' y + y y' = 2 y y'$$

Comment: Two words: chain rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe $y$ is to be understood as a function of $x$; thus by the chain rule

$(y^2)' = \dfrac{d(y^2)}{dy} \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2y \dfrac{dy}{dx}  = 2yy';  \tag 1$

therefore,

$y'' = 2x - (y^2)' = 2x - 2yy. \tag 2$